# UISplitViewController inside UITabBarVC: showDetail and hide tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitview

When I try to show view controller in `UISplitView`, I need to hide tab bar. I try use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`, but its not works. Is it possible to hide tab bar on `showDetail` without smell code? (like `viewwillappear` etc)

Answer (score 1):

Without code, it's not possible to do so. Add these lines in splitViewController class.

Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this when you want to hide your tab bar:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```